# Changing site theme when rendering a new Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently learning React (v15.6) through a web project that uses react-router (v4.1) for routing.  The high-level goal is this: **Change the site's theme when rendering the corresponding route.**

So for example, I want to use Theme Giraffe when the user goes to `/giraffe` and Theme Rhino when the user goes to `/rhino`.

I've taken a couple of approaches, each of which work but have suboptimal compromises.  My question is: *What is the most Reacty way of accomplishing this goal?*

Here is what I've tried so far and reasons why I'm hesitant employing them.  For both, my App renders the following:

```
<Page>
  <Route exact path='/' />
  <Route exact path='/giraffe' />
  <Route exact path='/rhino' />
</Page>
```

### Exhibit A: Using State

My first instinct was to go to state.  That is, set the state of the App to have some theme and pass that theme to the `<Page>` component on render:

```
<Page className={`theme-${this.state.theme}`}>
```

That's cool, but where do I set the state?  It needs to happen when a new route is rendered, so I did the following with the routes:

```
<Route exact path='/giraffe' render={() => this._renderWithTheme('giraffe', Giraffe)} />
// ...
_renderWithTheme(newTheme, component) {
  if(this.state.theme !== newTheme)
    this.setState({ theme: newTheme });
  return React.createElement(component);
}
```

**The Problem**: Even though this works, it requires changing the state while in the render step.  React prints a ton of warnings about this, plus the entire thing needs to render twice (once for the new route, and once for the new state).

### Exhibit B: The Routes render the Page

The next idea was to render the `<Page>` with the Route's renderer rather than render it above the Routes, like so:

```
<Route exact path='/giraffe' render={() => this._renderWithTheme('giraffe', Giraffe)} />
// ...
_renderWithTheme(newTheme, component) {
  const className = `theme-${newTheme}`;
  const child = React.createElement(component);
  return <Page className={className}>{child}</Page>;
}
```

**The Problem**: This time there are no warnings, but navigation becomes slightly wonky.  The issue is that since rendering a new route now re-renders the Page, the *entire* page, including static elements like the header and footer, are re-rendered.  Only the stuff between the header and footer needs to be updated, though, so it seems like a compromise at best to re-render everything when I just want to change a single classname.

---

**Goal**: Change the site's theme when rendering the corresponding route.

**Question**: What is the most Reacty way of accomplishing this goal without needing to re-render the entire page or change state in the render step?

Let me know if I need to clarify something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Redux to accomplish this, which I know is not technically "Reacty". React and Redux play very nicely together.

Using Redux, you can create what is called a **store** where you can store data that can be connected to any given React component that needs that data.

You could create a Redux store where you define (and the user can change) the theme setting and connect it to your Page component, which could render differently according to the selected theme.

You would not even need separate routes to accomplish this.

Check out the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/) to learn more. Though it may seem like a lot (it is a whole different animal (get it?) than React) but it is a fantastic tool and I highly recommend it. You would likely find many other uses for it in your app as well.